# Pgfplot, circumference doesn't reach x-axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

When plotting a (quarter of) circumference with `TikZ` and `pgfplot`, it doesn't touch the `x = 0` horizontal line:

[image]

Maybe this is due to the finite horizontal resolution of the plot, which in this case uses `8000` points. An increase of the number of points slowers the creation of the final `pdf` and doesn't let the curve reach `x = 0` anyway. Here is the original code:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    domain=0:2*pi,samples=8000,grid=major,
    width=15cm,
    \addplot [color=red] {sqrt(1.1 - x^2)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Is it possible to plot a **complete** quarter of circumference, letting it clearly be from the `y` axis to the `x` axis, regardless of the `samples` value? Is there any directive that can be used for this purpose with `TikZ` and/or `pgfplot`?

Comment: This is a usual problem when drawing circles using the explicit coordinate representation. Try to use a polar plot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    domain=0:2*pi,samples=100,grid=major,
    width=15cm,]
    \addplot[color=red, trig format plots=rad, domain=0:0.5*pi] ({sqrt(1.1) * cos(x)}, {sqrt(1.1) * sin(x)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The domain in the question already starts with angles, but the formula uses the formula:

*y* = sqrt(*r*<sup>2</sup> - *x*<sup>2</sup>)

With 50 samples and marked points:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    domain=0:2*pi,
    samples=50,
    grid=major,
    width=15cm,
]
    \addplot+[color=red] {sqrt(1.1 - x^2)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Before]

Findings:

- The domain is too large (0 to 2π≈6.28). The upper border is below 1.1, exactly sqrt(1.1).
- The rightmost point can theoretically never be hit, if the domain is given with rational numbers. At least, the domain should end there to get the point on the x-axis.

Changed:

```
domain=0:sqrt(1.1),
```

> [image: Result with fixed domain]

Still, lots of points are needed to get a smooth right side, because the points are not evenly distributed on the curve. This can be fixed by specifying the points in polar coordinates. Also `smooth` is added to be able to further reduce the number of samples.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    domain=0:90,
    samples=10,
    grid=major,
    width=15cm,
]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\radius}{sqrt(1.1)}
    \addplot+[color=red, smooth] ({\radius*cos(x)}, {\radius*sin(x)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with polar coordinates]